# mysql_real_escape works locally but not remote

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

When using mysql_real_escape_string on my local MAMP setup it works fine. Example when I enter "test" into a text field it appears \"test\".

When I publish this to the remote server it does not seem to be escaping the string. "test" appears as "test" in the database.

I have already made sure there is a connection open before escaping.

Example code:

```
    global $db,$db_table_prefix; 

    mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());

    $title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
    $content = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['content']);
```

It saves fine to the correct database and what not but just does not seem to be adding the \'s.

Comment: it should appear as "test" in the db, the \ are for escaping input, and are not stored. sounds like the local version is the wrong one.

Comment: Are you sure, the correct encoding is set? Also, that's what is supposed to appear in the database, isn't it? It 'passes' \"test\", but writes '"test"'.

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql_/).

Comment: i think i will go (more) insane seeing the "don't use mysql comment" on every mysql post. Are you going to add this to the millions of  existing mysql questions on S.O ?

Comment: @Dragon So from what I understand, the slashes should NOT be in the database?

Comment: @TheTechBox correct, unless you actully want them.

Comment: @Matt, your famous on Meta - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143379/automatically-warn-against-the-use-of-mysql-functions-on-stack-overflow - but really, please stop.

Comment: @Dragon and them not appearing still means that the inputs are still secure when using the code in the example?

Comment: @Dagon HA! THAT'S AWESOME. I'll tone it down.

Comment: @TheTechBox - correct - well if secure = wont break the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`magic_quotes` might be enabled on your local server. You would need to disable them.

More about disabling `magic_quotes`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Comment: If I disable them locally that means that they still won't work on the remote server?

Comment: @TheTechBox this is about server configuration. Since it is now deprecated it is recommended to disable them. You may use the "disabling magic quotes at runtime" part on your website which will cancel the effects of magic_quotes (Although it's better to disable them in the configuration)

Comment: I may be missing something but should the server BE adding the quotes when I escape the string? It isn't at the moment on the remote server but it is on the local.

Comment: @TheTechBox it's a legacy security feature that doesn't work. Don't rely on magic_quotes. You should also consider switching to mysqli or PDO. (Although it won't fix your current problem) and no, it doesn't add the quotes, only the backslashes.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say slashes not quotes.

Comment: The slashes are a magic_quotes option feature that is now deprecated. You should disable this option in your php.ini of your local server.

Comment: This was an absolute life saver!!

Answer (score 4):

That is not m_r_e_s's doing, but [magic_quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php). 
Your local machine has them enabled. Your remote does not. You ought to disable them locally.

Also, you really ought to start using [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Don't simply use `mysqli` or `PDO`, use **prepared queries** with them.

Comment: i always forget magic_quotes, they are just to insane to have every existed.

Comment: If I disable them locally that means that they still won't work on the remote server?

Comment: You need to modify your code not to rely on them. m_r_e_s is doing as it should, and does not care about magic_quotes. Again, switch to using mysqli or PDO (with prepared queries) and avoid all this mres mess.